# Which active MLB player has the highest Body Mass Index of the league?

Tags: baseball, trivia, mlb

I've been reading about Bartolo Colon and got intrigued: Which active MLB player has the highest Body Mass Index of the league?

Comment: Does this essentially mean who is the fattest?

Comment: Essentially, yes. That said, BMI is actually a very crude measure of being fat: given the fact that muscle weighs more than fat, body builders are usually obese by BMI metrics, although they have virtually no body fat. Not the case of Prince Fielder though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [list](http://xfinity.comcast.net/slideshow/sports-10fattestbaseballplayers/11/) states that the active MLB player with the highest Body Mass Index is [Prince Fielder](http://www.baseball-reference.com/players/f/fieldpr01.shtml) at 38.4.

Note: Prince Fielder is currently* listed at 5'11" 275 lbs. for a BMI of 38.4. However, Bartolo Colon is currently* listed at 5'11" 285 lbs. (265 lbs. in reference list, circa 2011) for a BMI of 39.7.  Depending on current* listings, this would make Bartolo Colon as the active MLB player with the highest Body Mass Index, but this may vary when we consider **listed weight** vs. **actual weight**.

<sub>*As of the 2014 MLB season</sub>

Comment: When the Mets picked up Colon this offseason, every restaurateur in Queens rejoiced.

Comment: I vote for Prince Fielder. Michael Lewis reported in Moneyball, "Prince Fielder is too fat even for the Oakland As. Of no other player in the [2002] draft can this be said." And that included Jeremy Brown.